DB2 temporarily prevent log files from being written to the archive log dir?
DB2 11.5.7.0 on Linux
We've got a cron job that does:
cd ${ARCH_LOC}
tar -czvf /path/to-backups/${DB}_ARCHIVELOG_${NOW}.tar.gz S*.LOG && rm -vf S*.LOG >> ${SLOG}

ISTM that there's a flaw her, since any archived log files written to $ARCH_LOC while the tar is running will get rmed but not saved.
Thus, is there any way to suspend the archiving of log files, and then resume it after the tar ... && rm completes?

Did you consider turning on compression of the archived logs, to avoid the need to do it yourself?

@mustaccio I have, but I'm not even close to being a proficient UDB DBA, so don't want to start mucking around until I'm more sure of things on this inherited system.

The best is to let db2 handle compression. If not possible I would use --remove-files as an argument to tar and get rid of the rm part. man tar: --remove-files
Remove files from disk after adding them to the archive.

You can find info about compression her: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=considerations-archived-log-file-compression
